# Question regarding path independence

Tags: calculus

I've been wracking my brain to try and figure out why the following works:

The question is asking whether $$\int F \, dr $$ is independent of path. We have a hint, that is (compute $$\int_a F \, dr $$ and $$\int_b F \, dr $$ where a and b are the upper/lower halves of the circle $x^2 + y^2 =1$ from $(1,0)$ to $(-1,0)$.

So we parametrize $a$ and $b$, saying $a = r(t) = \langle \cos t, \sin t \rangle$, and $b = r(t) = \langle \cos t, -\sin t \rangle$. both have the bounds of $0 \leq t \leq \pi$.

This is fine, but the issue is when we actually get to obtaining the line integral. In the answer key: [image]

I have NO idea how we're obtaining these values. why is $x^2$ + $y^2$ in the denominator? Why are we using -$y$ in both? Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Is there no vector field $F$ given in the first place?

Comment: Where's the question from? Surely it defined $\bf F$ somewhere?

Comment: Evidently we have $\vec F=\frac{-\hat xy+\hat yx}{x^2+y^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\vec F=\frac{-\hat xy+\hat yx}{x^2+y^2}$.  So, it is $\vec F$ that carries the term $x^2+y^2$ in the denominator.

Note that on the unit circle, we have $x^2+y^2=1$.

For the contour $C^{+}$ in the upper-half circle, parameterize with $x=\cos t$ and $y=\sin t$.  Thus, $dx=-\sin t\,dt$ and $dy=\cos t\,dt$ and $0<t<\pi$.

$$\begin{align}
\int_{C^{+}}\vec F\cdot d\vec r&=\int_0^{\pi} \frac{-y(t)x'(t)+x(t)y'(t)}{x^2(t)+y^2(t)}\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^{\pi} \left(\frac{\sin^2 t+\cos^2}{\sin^2 t+\cos^2}\right)=\pi
\end{align}$$

For the contour $C^{-}$ in the lower-half circle, parameterize with $x=\cos t$ and $y=-\sin t$.  Thus, $dx=-\sin t\,dt$ and $dy=-\cos t\,dt$ and $0<t<\pi$.  Note that we begin at $(1,0)$ and end at $(-1,0)$ with $y\le 0$ here.

$$\begin{align}
\int_{C^{+}}\vec F\cdot d\vec r&=\int_0^{\pi} \frac{-y(t)x'(t)+x(t)y'(t)}{x^2(t)+y^2(t)}\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^{\pi} \left(\frac{-\sin^2 t-\cos^2}{\sin^2 t+\cos^2}\right)=-\pi
\end{align}$$

as expected!